# Header that apears after scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a secondary header that appears after scrolling down (When my actual header disappears). I tried a jquery plugin called 'Headhesive', but no luck. Here is what I am asking for
https://markgoodyear.com/labs/headhesive
Here when the main header disappears, the second header appears, which is fixed one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a example for you here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zorken17/67csay9y/1/)

Or you can have a look at the snippet below

```js
// Options
var options = {
  // Scroll offset. Accepts Number or "String" (for class/ID)
  offset: 1, // OR — offset: '.classToActivateAt',

  // Custom classes
  classes: {

    // Cloned elem class
    clone: 'banner--clone',

    // Stick class
    stick: 'banner--stick',

    // Unstick class
    unstick: 'banner--unstick'
  },

  // Throttle scroll event to fire every 250ms to improve performace
  throttle: 250,

  // Callbacks
  onInit: function() {},
  onStick: function() {},
  onUnstick: function() {},
  onDestroy: function() {},
}

// Create a new instance of Headhesive and pass in some options
var header = new Headhesive('.banner', options);
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/markgoodyear/headhesive.js/master/demo/css/headhesive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/markgoodyear/headhesive.js/master/dist/headhesive.min.js"></script>
<header class="banner">
  My New Header/Navigation
</header>
```

Comment: Have you linked the correct js and css files to your project/page?

Comment: Copy your template to jsfiddle and I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write out all the code for you, but this might give you an idea of how to achieve what you want.

- Add a `scroll` event listener to the document body.
- Check if the document has scrolled past a certain point
- If the document has scrolled past a certain point, hide your 'first' header, and display the 'second' header.

The second header could simply have a CSS of a `top` and `left` of `0px` with a `position absolute`, making the header appear at the top of the page.

An example for listening to the scroll position:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll () {
    var scrollPosition = window.scrollY,
        showHeaderPosition = 100;

    // Determine if position is at a certain point
    if (scrollPosition >= showHeaderPosition) {
        showHeader();
    } else {
        hideHeader();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This page shows how to use the plugin you've shown, instructing how to show the header near another class and so on. 
http://www.cssscript.com/simple-on-demand-sticky-header-with-pure-js-headhesive-js/